# Preventing Derived Class calling Base class's public method

Tags: c++, inheritance, idioms

I am writing a base class that provides a public `update()` method. When someone derives from this base class, they must implement a pure virtual method that controls a tiny bit of the behavior of this update. This means that a.) `update()` needs to be public and b.) `update()` will need to call the pure virtual method in the derived class (which I make private just for safety).

However, I have just become aware of the possibility that the person writing the derived class could accidentally implement the pure virtual function and call `update()` inside there. This would lead to an infinite number of function calls, which would only be detected at runtime.

Is there some c++ idiom or keyword that would throw compiler errors if someone tried this?

Here is some example code. The person who wrote `Derived` didn't break the rules, but the person who wrote `DerivedBad` did.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
private:

    virtual void add_to_sum(int incr) = 0;
public:
    Base() : m_sum(0), m_other(0) {}
    void update(int incr, double other){
        this->add_to_sum(incr);
        m_other = other;
    }
    void print_everything() const{
        std::cout << "sum: " << m_sum << "\n";
        std::cout << "other: " << m_other << "\n";
    }
protected:
    int m_sum;
private:
    double m_other;
};

class Derived : public Base{
    virtual void add_to_sum(int incr) override{
        this->m_sum += incr;
    }
};

class DerivedBad : public Base{
    virtual void add_to_sum(int incr) override{
        this->m_sum += incr;
        this->update(incr, 3.0); // BAD!
    }
};
int main() {

//  Derived d;
    DerivedBad d;
    d.update(3, 42);
    d.print_everything();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing I can think of other than "Document the <expletive deleted> out of it."

Comment: As far as I know, the pure virtual method you're trying to protect should be 'protected' rather than 'private'.

Comment: @FCo Not necessary. The derived classes are implementing `add_to_sum`, not calling it. If there was a good way to prevent the derived classes from calling their own function as well, it would probably be time well spent.

Comment: Perhaps a pure virtual function is too flexible. Maybe the base class could have some pointer member that lets the derived class writer choose among a pre-fixed set of functionalities nstead of being expected to write his own from scratch.

Comment: @Taylor -- generally speaking, having that much coupling between a base class and derived classes is a bad idea. You'll spend all your time fielding support questions asking for additional options.

Comment: You could declare the method as private and make entities that need to use the method as a `friend`.  Remember, if a method is `public`, any function or class instance can access it including children and other generations.

Comment: The users of your class can create a potentially infinite number of bugs, why this particular one draws your special attention?

Answer (score 1):

The language itself can't help you here — a `public` method is public, nothing can prevent anyone from using it.

Documentation is good — you can mention this problem as a pitfall, but of course users will find other ways to shoot themselves in the foot.

Another way would be to rename your `update` method: the generic name doesn't say what the method does, so users will say "I don't really know what it does, but one `update` too many is better than nothing at all". If you give it a longer and a more specific name, maybe it will not make sense to call it from derived classes.

Another idea for naming: if the public method is called `update_all` and the overridden methods are all called `update_xxx`, `update_yyy`, ..., then it would be less natural to make such a call.

You could also hold a dedicated member which says "currently updating", then you can detect this situation at run-time and throw an exception before it enters an infinite recursion.